# Do I need a Hong Kong transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, hong-kong, iraqi-citizens

I am an Iraqi passport holder residing in the United Arab Emirates. I have a connecting flight through Hong Kong, and I will neither be staying in Hong Kong city nor leaving the airside area. I will fly to Hong Kong from Dubai with Cathay Pacific, and I will stay in the airport for almost 5 hours and a half. After that I will depart Hong Kong to Tokyo (Japan).

Do I need a transit visa for that?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Hong_Kong#Transit_visa_required) seems to think so. Which is confirmed by [HK Immigration's website](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html).

Comment: It is the same source actually, because Wikipedia information is based on HK Immigration website.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the sentence order. I went to wikipedia (which is one should do first anyway)  and followed the link for Iraq to HK Immigration (which would have been anyway my second stop). So the order I did things is reflected in my sentence.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IQ&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=HK&selDest=Hong%20Kong%20%28SAR%20China%29&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a Hong Kong (SAR
>   China) Permanent Identity Card [or] a travel document
>   issued by Hong Kong (SAR China) with "Holder's eligibility for
>   Hong Kong (SAR China) Permanent Identity Card verified.

So yes, you need a transit visa.