# Does an Iranian need a transit visa in Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, transit, hong-kong, iranian-citizens

I want to go Japan and I have a visa for that. I'm Iranian. I am coming from Mumbai with a transit in Hong Kong. Do I need a Hong Kong visa for this 3-hour transit?

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102786/do-i-need-a-hong-kong-transit-visa

Answer (score 1):

As per [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=00&TR=HK&selDest=Hong%20Kong%20%28SAR%20China%29&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a Hong Kong (SAR
>   China) Permanent Identity Card.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a travel document
>   issued by Hong Kong (SAR China) with "Holder's eligibility for
>   Hong Kong (SAR China) Permanent Identity Card verified  .

So yes, you need a transit visa.